# vsnprintf returns the size over given buffer size

Tags: c++, c, linux, api

Very long string with myPrint() function is going to crash.

I thought that vsnprintf() cannot return the written size over buffer length from linux man page.

My expected string is truncated string in buffer size but that's totally wrong from below test code.

What is wrong below??

```
void myPrint(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    char buffer[512] = {0,};

    va_list arg;
    va_start(arg, fmt);

    int r = vsnprintf(buffer, 511, fmt, arg); // buffer size is given
    if (r > 0)              // works correctly
        buffer[r+1] = '\0'; // crash because r is 200,000
    va_end(arg);
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    const char * data = "abcdefg...." // assuming that a length is 200,000 byte string
    myPrint("%s\n", data);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to terminate string after call, `vsnprintf` already does that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the `vsnprintf` very specifically returns the number of characters required for the full string. [C11 7.21.6.12p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.12p3):

> The vsnprintf function returns the number of characters that ***would have been written* had n been sufficiently large, not counting the terminating null character**, or a negative value if an encoding error occurred. Thus, the null-terminated output has been completely written if and only if the returned value is nonnegative and less than n.

Additionally, the input size should be the full buffer size, e.g. here 512. Then `vsnprintf` would write up to 511 characters and add the terminating `'\0'` after the last character written. [(C11 snprintf description)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.5p2):

> Otherwise, output characters beyond the n-1st are discarded rather than being written to the array, and a null character is written at the end of the characters actually written into the array. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

Additionally, note that ([7.21.6.5p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.5p2)):

> [...] Thus, the null-terminated output has been completely written if and only if the returned value is nonnegative and less than n.

That is, if your buffer is an array of 512 `char` and you passed in 512, the string was properly written and not truncated iff the return `n` value of `*snprintf` is `0 <= n <= 511`

---

Beware that the Microsoft Visual C++ had a very broken function by the name [`_vsnprintf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kt27hek.aspx) that:

> [...] return the number of characters written if the number of characters to write is less than or equal to count; **if the number of characters to write is greater than count, these functions return -1 indicating that output has been truncated.**

---

Finally, if you're writing only Linux / Glibc specific code, you could also consider using `vasprintf` that would dynamically allocate a buffer large enough to hold the entire string.

Comment: Note that there are numerous other old implementations of the `*snprintf()` family of functions that also returned `-1` on output truncation.  That was one of the two major variations of behavior that existed before widespread standardization of C.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yeah, `snprintf` is C99

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple things to fix here:

1. You can give complete buffer size to `vsnprintf`:

   ```
   int r = vsnprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, fmt, arg);
   ```
2. You don't need to nul terminate buffer after call. `vsnprintf` truncates too long string correctly.
3. `vsnprintf` returns the length that would have been, if truncation hadn't happened. If you need to detect truncation, you can do it as follows:

   ```
   if(r >= sizeof buffer) {
        // Buffer was too small    
   }
   ```